# File Upload control is not able to give back the correct content..Extra characters are appending

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a file upload control.And I have to read a file content.

The actual file content is

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.ws_Device_Update
(
    @ApplicationId uniqueidentifier   ,
    @OriginalApplicationId uniqueidentifier   ,
    @DeviceIMEI nvarchar (50)  ,
    @OriginalDeviceIMEI nvarchar (50)  ,
    @ModelId int   ,
    @DeviceName nvarchar (50)  ,
    @DeviceDescription nvarchar (255)  ,
    @DeviceState int   ,
    @IsExpired bit   ,
    @IsSuspended bit   ,
    @LastAccessed datetime   ,
    @ClientSeqNo bigint   ,
    @ServerSeqNo bigint   ,
    @ModelCode varchar (50)  ,
    @PushToken varchar (512)  ,
    @PushLastAlive datetime   ,
    @PushLastDead datetime   ,
    @DeviceType int   
)
AS
```

And I am using the below program

```
int fileLength = fileUpload.PostedFile.ContentLength;            
Byte[] contentInBytes = new Byte[fileLength];
using (Stream streamContent = fileUpload.FileContent)
{
  streamContent.Read(contentInBytes, 0, fileLength);
}
var xx = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(contentInBytes);
```

The output that I am getting is

```
???CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.ws_Device_Update
(
    @ApplicationId uniqueidentifier   ,
    @OriginalApplicationId uniqueidentifier   ,
    @DeviceIMEI nvarchar (50)  ,
    @OriginalDeviceIMEI nvarchar (50)  ,
    @ModelId int   ,
    @DeviceName nvarchar (50)  ,
    @DeviceDescription nvarchar (255)  ,
    @DeviceState int   ,
    @IsExpired bit   ,
    @IsSuspended bit   ,
    @LastAccessed datetime   ,
    @ClientSeqNo bigint   ,
    @ServerSeqNo bigint   ,
    @ModelCode varchar (50)  ,
    @PushToken varchar (512)  ,
    @PushLastAlive datetime   ,
    @PushLastDead datetime   ,
    @DeviceType int   
)
AS
```

Some extra **???** characters are coming ...i don't know from where?

The byte array produced was

```
239,187,191,67,82,69,65,84,69,32,80,82,79,67,69,68,85,82,69,32,100,98,111,46,119,115,95,68,101,118,105,99,101,95, 85,112,100,97,116,101,13,10,40,13,10,9,64,65,112,112,108,105,99,97,116,105,111,110,73,100,32,117,110,105,113,117,               101,105,100,101,110,116,105,102,105,101,114,32,32,32,44,13,10,9,64,79,114,105,103,105,110,97,108,65,112,112,108,                105,99,97,116,105,111,110,73,100,32,117,110,105,113,117,101,105,100,101,110,116,105,102,105,101,114,32,32,32,44,                13,10,9,64,68,101,118,105,99,101,73,77,69,73,32,110,118,97,114,99,104,97,114,32,40,53,48,41,32,32,44,13,10,9,64,                79,114,105,103,105,110,97,108,68,101,118,105,99,101,73,77,69,73,32,110,118,97,114,99,104,97,114,32,40,53,48,41,32,                32,44,13,10,9,64,77,111,100,101,108,73,100,32,105,110,116,32,32,32,44,13,10,9,64,68,101,118,105,99,101,78,97,109,                101,32,110,118,97,114,99,104,97,114,32,40,53,48,41,32,32,44,13,10,9,64,68,101,118,105,99,101,68,101,115,99,114,105,                112,116,105,111,110,32,110,118,97,114,99,104,97,114,32,40,50,53,53,41,32,32,44,13,10,9,64,68,101,118,105,99,101,83,                116,97,116,101,32,105,110,116,32,32,32,44,13,10,9,64,73,115,69,120,112,105,114,101,100,32,98,105,116,32,32,32,44,13,                10,9,64,73,115,83,117,115,112,101,110,100,101,100,32,98,105,116,32,32,32,44,13,10,9,64,76,97,115,116,65,99,99,101,115,                115,101,100,32,100,97,116,101,116,105,109,101,32,32,32,44,13,10,9,64,67,108,105,101,110,116,83,101,113,78,111,32,98,105,                103,105,110,116,32,32,32,44,13,10,9,64,83,101,114,118,101,114,83,101,113,78,111,32,98,105,103,105,110,116,32,32,32,44,13,                10,9,64,77,111,100,101,108,67,111,100,101,32,118,97,114,99,104,97,114,32,40,53,48,41,32,32,44,13,10,9,64,80,117,115,104,84,                111,107,101,110,32,118,97,114,99,104,97,114,32,40,53,49,50,41,32,32,44,13,10,9,64,80,117,115,104,76,97,115,116,65,108,105,                118,101,32,100,97,116,101,116,105,109,101,32,32,32,44,13,10,9,64,80,117,115,104,76,97,115,116,68,101,97,100,32,100,97,116,                101,116,105,109,101,32,32,32,44,13,10,9,64,68,101,118,105,99,101,84,121,112,101,32,105,110,116,32,32,32,13,10,41,13,10,65,83
```

I don't know from where "239,187,191" has come...any clue on how to solve this?

Thanks

Comment: May be, it is unicode byte order mark.

Comment: so how to handle it ?and it is not happening for all other files..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is unicode byte order mark.
Use `var xx = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(contentInBytes);`.

Answer (score 4):

`239 187 191` represents `UTF-8` [Byte order mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)

Try [`StreamReader Constructor (String, Encoding, Boolean)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/akzyzwh9.aspx) it has parameter to detect encoding

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileUpload.FileContent, 
                  Encoding.Unicode, true);

string fromFile= reader.ReadToEnd();
```